# R add time zone offset to POSIXct class

Tags: r, timezone-offset

Is there an easy way to add time zone offset to an existing timestamp (all in UTC)?

For simplicity, I am using `Sys.time()` in my example, but in the actual data, I do `DF$ts <- as.POSIXct(..., tz="GMT")`.

```
DF <- data.frame("ts" = rep(Sys.time(), 5),
                 "offset"=c("-11:00", "-12:00", "+01:30", "+02:00", "+02:30"))

# > DF
#                    ts offset
# 1 2015-09-02 14:35:31 -11:00
# 2 2015-09-02 14:35:31 -12:00
# 3 2015-09-02 14:35:31 +01:30
# 4 2015-09-02 14:35:31 +02:00
# 5 2015-09-02 14:35:31 +02:30
```

Right now I am doing string manipulation, but I don't think that is elegant. For example,

```
offsetSeconds <- function(offset) {
  time <- as.numeric(strsplit(offset, ":")[[1]])
  seconds <- time[1] * 3600 + sign(time[1]) * time[2] * 60
  return(seconds)
}
DF$seconds <- as.numeric(sapply(as.character(DF$offset), offsetSeconds))
DF$local_ts <- DF$ts + DF$seconds

# > DF
#                    ts offset seconds            local_ts
# 1 2015-09-02 14:35:31 -11:00  -39600 2015-09-02 03:35:31
# 2 2015-09-02 14:35:31 -12:00  -43200 2015-09-02 02:35:31
# 3 2015-09-02 14:35:31 +01:30    5400 2015-09-02 16:05:31
# 4 2015-09-02 14:35:31 +02:00    7200 2015-09-02 16:35:31
# 5 2015-09-02 14:35:31 +02:30    9000 2015-09-02 17:05:31
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(lubridate)
signs <- as.numeric(paste0(substr(DF$offset, 1, 1), "1"))
DF$ts + hm(DF$offset)*signs
#[1] "2015-09-02 04:06:17 EDT" "2015-09-02 03:06:17 EDT"
#[3] "2015-09-02 16:36:17 EDT" "2015-09-02 17:06:17 EDT"
#[5] "2015-09-02 17:36:17 EDT"
```

Using the function `hm` from the lubridate package, we can convert the text strings from the `offset` column into hour and minute spans. But since the positive and negative signs are ignored by the function, we have to multiply the hour/minute variable by the sign. I am assuming that, as in the example, there is a positive or negative sign for each offset.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two ways:

First, in the *formatting step* a timezone is applied:

```
R> t <- Sys.time()
R> sapply(c("America/New_York","America/Los_Angeles"),function(tz) format(t,tz=tz))
     America/New_York   America/Los_Angeles 
"2015-09-02 15:34:28" "2015-09-02 12:34:28" 
R>
```

Three hour difference as you would expect.

Second, and that is more hackish, just shift by seconds:

```
R> sapply(seq(-60,60,60), function(dt) format(t+dt*60, tz="America/New_York"))
[1] "2015-09-02 14:34:28" "2015-09-02 15:34:28" "2015-09-02 16:34:28"
R>
```

That is cleaner than your approach as you don't need the parsing.

Lastly, time-series containers like `xts` allow you to set a TZ attribute which is what I usually do for real data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My timezone offsets will always be in the format of UTC offsets, meaning it will always be in this format: `{+/-}{hour}:{min}`, e.g., `+11:00`, `-02:30`. Is there a function to map `-04:00` to `"America/New_York"`?

Comment: I think you misunderstand. In example two, I just use "any" TZ for the formatting; the key of that answer are the numeric offsets.  And yes, my package RcppBDT has some timezone helpers from Boost Date_Time which may help there.